# How do I list emails with attachment names using Microsoft Graph SDK?

Tags: .net, email-attachments, microsoft-graph-sdks

I can retrieve the emails and attachments using this code:

```
var emails = await graphServiceClient.Users["user@company.com"].MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages
            .Request()
            .Top(10)
            .Expand("attachments")
            .Select("subject,receivedDateTime,from,attachments")
            .GetAsync(cancellationToken);
```

However I'm not interested in the contents for the attachments (expanding the attachments is around 3x slower). Is it possible to get just the attachment names in a single call? If I leave out the `.Expand` then the `Attachments` property is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$select` in `Expand` to return only selected properties for expanded property.

```
var emails = await graphServiceClient.Users["user@company.com"].MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages
            .Request()
            .Top(10)
            .Expand("attachments($select=name)")
            .Select("subject,receivedDateTime,from,attachments")
            .GetAsync(cancellationToken);
```